# get data and push to array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following loop:

```
        for (let item of items) {
            if (item && withCognitoData) {
                try {
                    let defaultData
                    let legacyData
                    if (item.isMigrated) {
                        legacyData = await safelyGetCognitoUser({
                            cognitoProvider: legacyCognitoProvider,
                            email: item.email,
                        }) ||{}

                       ***defaultData = await safelyGetCognitoUser({
                            cognitoProvider: defaultCognitoProvider,
                            email: item.email,
                        }) || {} ***
                    } else if (!item.isMigrated) {
                        defaultData = await safelyGetCognitoUser({
                            cognitoProvider: defaultCognitoProvider,
                            email: item.email,
                        }) || {}
                        legacyData = {}
                    }
                    identitiesWithCognitoData.push({
                        ...item,
                        cognitoData: {
                            legacyCognitoData: legacyData,
                            defaultCognitoData: defaultData,
                        },
                    })
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

in case the user not found in `defaultData` in first if statement the `catch block` is running and the object (`legacyData` and `defaultData`) are not pushed to `identitiesWithCognitoData` array.
what i aim to do is in case there is no user in (`legacyData` or `defaultData`) then just push empty object

Answer (score 1):

Take the `push` outside of the `try` statement. Initialize `defaultData` and `legacyData` to empty objects, so the `push()` will use those defaults.

Also, there's no need to use `else if (!item.isMigrated)`. This condition is the opposite of the `if` condition, so just use `else`.

```js
for (let item of items) {
  if (item && withCognitoData) {
    try {
      let defaultData = {};
      let legacyData = {}
      if (item.isMigrated) {
        legacyData = await safelyGetCognitoUser({
          cognitoProvider: legacyCognitoProvider,
          email: item.email,
        })

        defaultData = await safelyGetCognitoUser({
          cognitoProvider: defaultCognitoProvider,
          email: item.email,
        })
      } else {
        defaultData = await safelyGetCognitoUser({
          cognitoProvider: defaultCognitoProvider,
          email: item.email,
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    identitiesWithCognitoData.push({
      ...item,
      cognitoData: {
        legacyCognitoData: legacyData,
        defaultCognitoData: defaultData,
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Barmar, i tried that before but it didn’t work :(